# how to add access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. in ionic 3

Tags: php, typescript, post, ionic3

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have developed a new application an ionic 3 , I have used localhost database to access values and have used of the api call. But button click event calling api give me an error in No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present on the requested resource.

[image]

Comment: @Moby_m .. yes but how to set in header an ionic 3 ?

Comment: finally , i hve find out problem solution ...  finally problem in angular 5 version in ....  Show in open in package.json file open and set to  
         "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "4.3.3",  update it is filed and now agin to run command npm install ....